# How to determine the value of an expression in integer form for python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have a doubt regarding a homework problem. I am unable to find the value of an expression in integer form.

The question is `c=(6-3)*(2+7)/3`.

What I have done is `print("c=(6-3) * (2+7)/3=", (6-3) * (2+)/3)`
I have gotten the value 9.0 so what expression should I write in order for me to get 9 and not 9.0?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using multiplication and division your answer gets converted to float, so at the end you simply have to convert it to integer.
So you can try this:

```
print("c=(6-3) * (2+7)/3=", int((6-3) * (2+7)/3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using Python 3 since you are getting a float when performing a regular division or multiplication. You have two possible options:

You can cast the result using the built-int `int`

```py
print("c=(6-3) * (2+7)/3=", int((6 - 3) * (2 + 7) / 3))
```

You can use integer division `//`

```py
print("c=(6-3) * (2+7)/3=", int((6 - 3) * (2 + 7) // 3))
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
c=(6-3) * (2+7)/3= 9
```

Comment: @Jade, if you don't mind. I would appreciate you upvote/validate my answer.